# Can we use some filter along with Json path while using Mergeyaml recipe

Tags: openrewrite

I have to add some addition key-value pair in my YAML file. But `Mergeyaml` offers only JsonPath expression used to find matching keys. Can we apply some filter or condition along with Json path like if it matches then only add the key.

Ex: `parameters` with `openJdkVersion: 17` need to add in below YAML, so it should looks like:-

```
stages:
  - template: templates/my-java-service-v1.yaml@codeway
    parameters:
      openJdkVersion: 17
```

Can we writer recipe something like add `openJDKVersion` only if template is `templates/my-java-service-v1.yaml@codeway`

```
recipeList:
   - org.openrewrite.yaml.MergeYaml:
      key: $.stages[?(@.template==templates/my-java-service-v1.yaml@codeway)]
      yaml: |-
        parameters:
          openJdkVersion: 17
      acceptTheirs: null
      objectIdentifyingProperty: name
```

I tried, but this template condition filter does not work. it add even there is no template. Please provide if some alternative way available.